# How do I set the default search for Finder to filenames which INCLUDE the search term (rather than just begin with it)? Yosemite

Tags: macos, finder, search

I'm using Yosemite (OS X 10.10.1).  If I search for the term "foo" and want a list of all files that include that term, I get foo.doc and bar.foo.doc and foodstuffs.xlsx and even The Foo History.  But it does not include snafoos.docx and AllTheFooReports.xlsx.  How can I change it to the (obvious!?!) behaviour of returning all results which include the search term?

I'd like to be able to do this from within Finder, not just in terminal.

Comment: I'm seeing e.g. barfoo.txt in a simple Finder search from the top toolbar - pretty sure it's always done that

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Perhaps it's a setting that has gone astray for me.  But I am NOT getting internal text strings, unless they are separated by _ or . or spaces.

Comment: hmm… I'm really not sure - maybe clear search prefs. Google seems to think that clearing Finder prefs would do it, but I'm not certain - this has instructions… http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/finder.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Finder searches for word prefixes.

If you save your search as a Smart Folder and then inspect that using a text editor (e.g. TextMate) you will see the raw Spotlight query:

```
((kMDItemDisplayName = "foo*"cdw))
```

The "w" modifier tells Spotlight to search for words. The "*" wildcard at the end of the search string makes Spotlight search for word prefixes. It will match names that contain a word beginning with "foo".

That matches all of your examples but one. "foo" comes at the start of the file name, after a space or punctuation or is capitalized. The exception is "snafoos" where "foo" is just a sequence of letters in the middle of the word.

You could change the query in the smart folder to:

```
((kMDItemDisplayName = "*foo*"cd))
```

Or click the "+" button below the search field in Finder and add a "name" "contains" "foo" criterion.

Or use mdfind in Terminal:

```
mdfind -onlyin . '((kMDItemDisplayName = "*foo*"cd))'
```

Or use [HoudahSpot](http://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot) (of which I am the developer) to get more control over your search.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.  Still baffled that Finder operates this way!  Your mention of  using the +  in an existing search to specify "name" "contains" does what I need.  Ideally I'd still like to make this the default search behaviour!  Does HoudahSpot allow for that?  I've heard good things about it before - I'll be checking it out!

Comment: @KathyO HoudahSpot lets you save the current configuration (criteria, search locations, columns, sort order, …) "as default": New searches will open to that setup. It also lets you save templates for recurring searches.

Comment: @PierreBernard do you have a source for the behaviour of the "w" modifier by any chance? I can't find any mention of it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html

Comment: @JoeTaylor Can't find any documentation. I may have inferred this from queries created by the Finder.

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck you could use a find command in a terminal window.

Open a terminal window and type :$ `find . -iname \*foo\*`

Here's an example using the files you mentioned in your question.

```
mgagnon-mbp:tmp mgagnon$ ls
AllTheFooReports.xlsx   bar.foo.doc     foo.doc         foodstuffs.xlsx     snafoos.docx

mgagnon-mbp:tmp mgagnon$ find . -iname \*foo\*
./AllTheFooReports.xlsx
./bar.foo.doc
./foo.doc
./foodstuffs.xlsx
./snafoos.docx
```

If you're not familiar with the terminal this is a fun way to learn! :) The easiest way to open a terminal windows is using a spotlight search (command-spacebar) and search for terminal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Gagnon, that's good to know.  I'm an old Unix user so can do all right in terminal, but was looking for a way to do this within the OSX GUI.  I have never broken the habit of my Unix style filenames, which never had a spaces and silly punctuation that didn't serve a specific purpose!  Good reminder that in a bind, this approach would work though.