# mdfind using -name option

Tags: macos, command-line, spotlight, search, metadata

I get this result:

```
 user@10 $  mdfind kind:application -name "Seashore" -onlyin /Volumes/WD\ Elements
/Volumes/WD Elements/backup 2018/Desktop/Seashore.app
/Volumes/WD Elements/backup Juli 2021/Desktop/Seashore.app
/Volumes/WD Elements/Backup 2020 Aug/Desktop/Seashore.app
```

But then I get this:

```
user@10 $ mdfind kind:application -name "*shore" -onlyin /Volumes/WD\ Elements  
 user@10 $
```

I tried with different wildcards and need help. Is it possible to to search for text in the middle of a name?

Comment: What feels odd to me is that `mdfind` assumes wildcards… but only as "begins with" rather than "contains". `-name "Micro"` returns all the Microsoft apps, but `-name "soft"` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The **-name** shortcut is for exact searches only (at least according to the `man` page of a tool [where the documentation isn’t always correct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/388210/5472)), so you’re telling it to look for names with literal * in them. Instead, you want to use the kMDItemDisplayName or kMDItemFSName fields. You can learn what these are with the `mdls` command to list one of the Applications you wish to find later with your excellent test example.

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName == '*shore*'"
```

Comment: Also, my brain works better with the “ == “ syntax as opposed to the [also valid (( = )) syntax](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178603/5472).

Comment: Ah yes, thank you @bmike! I'v tried playing around with the kMD options, but couldn't get myself to get them to work, but your answer worked. Thank you so much! I am planning on start using mdfind instead of Spotlight for files. Thanks again!